# Is it a good idea to use multiple database systems and ORMs in a single Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, postgresql, activerecord, mongoid

More specifically, I am thinking of using PostgreSQL (ActiveRecord) and MongoDB (Mongoid) in a single Rails 4 app.

Also, will associations between models work? Something like

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
end

class Order
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :customer
end
```

I am aware that ActiveRecord and Mongoid *can* coexist, but is that a good idea?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but just a suggestion: Recent postgres versions have `JSON` fields which can be indexed and queried. Mongodb has a whole lot more functionality in dealing with JSON objects, but for a lot of use cases, it's enough. You might not need two databases.

Comment: That is helpful, actually. Never knew that postgres can handle JSON. Thanks, @RikkusRukkus!

Comment: I do this, it works fine with a couple rolls of duct tape to hold things together. I don't think you'll get cross-database relations to work reliably though, better to do that by hand to limit your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do some hard thinking and try to choose one of the databases, even if you can make them work together technically.  You have to think past programming and take a bigger view.  One day your app will be in production, I assume.   THis implies 2 different backup solutions, 2 different monitoring solutions, double the training for the ops, etc.

Alex Lerner

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely OK.

If you application have different kind of data and using mongodb improve performance, why not?

OR:

Your application is market. Products in your market have common columns - price, name and etc. Put them in postgresql. 
Besides, products have many params are not common for all (computer - volume of hdd, monitor - size of display and etc). These data you can store using mongodb.